# Reference another dimen in dimen

Tags: android, android-resources, dimension

Is it possible to use the reference of a dimension resource in another dimension? What i mean is something like this:

File `dimen.xml`:

```
<dimen name="test1">18sp</dimen>
<dimen name="test2">@dimen/test1</dimen>
```

Comment: what would be the purpose of having two dimensions set to the same value?

Comment: maybe i want to have test2, test3 and test4 the same value as test1, but use it at different places in code. so if i want to change e.g. the value of test3, i can just change this value and the other ones are untouched

Comment: What did the compiler say?

Comment: actually i didn't try, because i suggest that it won't work?! but i will give this a try.

Comment: awesome, it works this way i posted :)

Comment: but you cant change the values of the resources once compiled so your reason for wanting duplicate values makes no sense

Comment: @RoyJamesSchumacher It makes much sense actually. If you're sure that some dimensions in your layouts will be the same *by definition*, then use the same `dimen`. However, if some dimensions are related in some way and happen to be the same, but *not* by definition, declare 2 dimensions, and refer to the other with `@dimen`. If you want to change the value at some point, the change will be in one place. If during development, you decide it shouldn't be the same value anymore, then change the reference also in one place only.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It works the way i posted

```
<dimen name="test1">18sp</dimen>
<dimen name="test2">@dimen/test1</dimen>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to consider one more thing when using this.
I get what you said in your comment, but either there is a link between the two values or there is not and you should distinguish between these two possibilities.

If there is *no* link between `test1` and `test2` and they are independent and the fact that they hold the same value is mere coincidence, then you shouldnt suggest a link between the two. Instead just set the same value twice.

Answer (score -4):

Why do you want create a second dimension with the same value as first ?

**Don't create second dimension, but use first !**

Comment: read my comment on the first post. maybe i want to change the value for one of these dimensions later time.

Comment: So create some variables !

Comment: And if you were to create variables, how would you reference them in layout files?